# asp.net dropdownlist postback

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a list of dropdownlist say A,B,C,D. All A, B, C pull data from the same table (table1). D pulls from a different one (table2, but would also use table1 in the sql query). What I want to achieve is once a value is pulled down from A, then the value from B,C,D are auto selected. 
My current asp code can only make that when a random value of Dropdown A is selected, B, C can get value selected automatically, but not D. The second time a random value from A is selected, all B, C, D get value selected.

My code is below:
A

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListA" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="country" DataValueField="country" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                       <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" Selected="True" />  </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct country from table1 order by country"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

B

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="GICS" DataValueField="GICS" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select distinct GICS, country from table1 where country=@country">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListA" Name="country" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListC" class="ddStyle" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="company" DataValueField="id" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select company, GICS, country, id from table1 where gics=@gics and country=@country">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListB" Name="gics" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListA" Name="Country" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

D

```
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select edition, company, id from table2 where table2.company in (select company from table1 where table1.id=@id)">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListC" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I wonder how to achieve that once a value is pulled down from A, then the value from B,C,D are auto selected (I guess the reason D isn't selected first is due to its sql query).
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: May be this is helpful: [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Comment: I'd say use an update panel. And use the first drop down as a trigger.